# All of the sudden getting Excel VBA error code 91: "Object variable or With block variable not set" after code had been working and no edits made

Tags: excel, vba

I had created a macro in VBA to track barcodes by day of the week. The idea was when that barcode gets scanned once, the time will go into the next cell (this is done with a formula and works great), at the end of the day, the materials must be scanned back in, so I made a macro for the top of each day (Monday is in cell A1). The idea is when the barcode gets scanned into cell A1, it will search through the data in the designated row (in my case row B), and when it finds that entry, it will put a time out stamp under the time in stamp.

This code had been working and I saved the excel file while I waited on my materials to arrive, so now that they are here and I wanted to do one last test run, it doesn't work and I am getting that error, although I have not changed anything... I have attached my code below and marked where I am getting the error message.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm stuck!

Code:

```
Private Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call monday
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call tuesday
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("K1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call wednesday
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("P1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call thursday
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("U1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call friday
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub monday()
Dim barcode As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim foundval As Range
Dim diff As Double


Dim rownumber As Long

barcode = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
If barcode <> "" Then
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("b5:b500").Find(what:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ActivrSheet.Cells(1, 1) = ""
    Else
        rownumber = rng.Row
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rownumber, 1), Cells(rownumber, 4)).Find("").Select #ERROR MESSAGE HERE!
        ActiveCell.Value = Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = ""
    End If
End If
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub

Sub tuesday()
Dim barcode As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim foundval As Range
Dim diff As Double

Dim rownumber As Long

barcode = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6)
If barcode <> "" Then
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("g:g").Find(what:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6) = ""
    Else
        rownumber = rng.Row
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rownumber, 6), Cells(rownumber, 9)).Find("").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6) = ""
    End If
End If
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6).Select
End Sub

Sub wednesday()
Dim barcode As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim foundval As Range
Dim diff As Double

Dim rownumber As Long

barcode = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 11)
If barcode <> "" Then
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("l:l").Find(what:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 11) = ""
    Else
        rownumber = rng.Row
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rownumber, 11), Cells(rownumber, 14)).Find("").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 11) = ""
    End If
End If
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 11).Select
End Sub

Sub thursday()
Dim barcode As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim diff As Double

Dim rownumber As Long

barcode = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 16)
If barcode <> "" Then
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("q:q").Find(what:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 16) = ""
    Else
        rownumber = rng.Row
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rownumber, 16), Cells(rownumber, 19)).Find("").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 16) = ""
    End If
End If
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 16).Select
End Sub

Sub friday()
Dim barcode As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim diff As Double

Dim rownumber As Long

barcode = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 21)
If barcode <> "" Then
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("v:v").Find(what:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 21) = ""
    Else
        rownumber = rng.Row
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rownumber, 21), Cells(rownumber, 24)).Find("").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 21) = ""
    End If
End If
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 21).Select
End Sub
```

See A1, where the barcode would be scanned
[image: Sheet here]
Error [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFHCD.png)

Comment: Your code could be much shorter overall, but it would be good to have a bit more detail around where the timestamps go.  A screenshot would be very useful.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added a photo to my post, EE1 shows what it might look like when info is filled out, then at the end of day the material barcodes would be scanned into the highlighted A1 cell, ideally it will look for that barcode (right now the barcode is "SCANNER 1" as a test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be much shorter, since much of it is repeated and the only variable is the column to be searched for the scanned barcode.

```vb
Private Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cBarcode As Range, barCode, f As Range, c As Range, rngSrch As Range

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    'data was changed in one of the cells we're monitoring?
    Set cBarcode = Application.Intersect(Target, _
                       Me.Range("A1,F1,K1,P1,U1"))
    If cBarcode Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    barCode = cBarcode.Value
    If Len(barCode) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    'locate barcode in the column to the right of cBarcode
    Set f = cBarcode.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Find( _
             what:=barCode, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
             MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then       'found a barcode match?
        Set rngSrch = Me.Cells(f.row, cBarcode.Column).Resize(1, 4) 'fixed from 3...
        Set c = rngSrch.Find("")
        If Not c Is Nothing Then   'any empty cell?
            c.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
            c.Value = Time
        Else
            MsgBox "No empty cells found in " & rngSrch.Address
        End If
    End If

    cBarcode.ClearContents   'clear the scanned code
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks great, and would make my code a lot shorter, thank you for the help! One error I'm running into when I try that is "Invalid use of Me keyword" I am fairly new to VBA and typically use other languages, but I have never gotten that error before, do you know how I would go about fixing that?

Comment: `worksheet_Change` is supposed to be in the sheet code module, where `Me` refers to the worksheet corresponding to the code module.  If you're getting that error then maybe you have the code in a regular module?

Comment: I hate to admit this, but I'm not even sure what that means.  I keep getting the Invalid Me keyword error, but I'm not sure what module I am in, I was under the impression that   there are Class, Object, and Standard Modules. Which should I be in and how do I verify I am? Thanks again, I really do appreciate it :)

Comment: On the worksheet where you're scanning your barcodes, right-click the sheet tab and select "View code" - that's where this code should be located.   Every woksheet in your workbook has a linked code module - you can see them in the tree in the VB editor "Project" pane, under "Microsoft Excel Objects", along with the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: Tim, I made it to that screen! I see first my VBA Project, under that are 3 folders: Microsoft Excel Objects (this has my sheet tabs (3) and then ThisWorkbook,  a Forms Folder, and a Modules folder (this is where I can find my module). I assume the code (Module1) is supposed to be under my sheet tab and not the Modules folder? Is that correct? Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes - move it to the sheet code module

Answer (score 1):

That line of code is searching in a specific row, cells A to D, searching for a blank cell.

You will get that error message if there is no blank cell in cells A to D in that row.

Comment: That is a good point, I checked and there are plenty of empty cells, I purposely made the range larger than what I need so there would be extra space. Thanks for the help!