# How to get a macro to run continuously as long as certain cell is selected?

Tags: excel, vba

Beginner here,

I'm wondering if there is a way to get a macro to run over and over as long as text is entered into a certain cell?

A barcode will be scanned into cell A1 and I have code that works for what I want it to do, now why isn't the macro automatically running again?

When I scan a code in I have to manually go to Developer tab > Macros > Run
I just want this to run as long as text keeps being entered

Here is my code

```
Private Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Target.Address = ("A1") Then
        Call monday
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub monday()
Dim barcode As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim foundval As Range
Dim diff As Double


Dim rownumber As Long

barcode = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
If barcode <> "" Then
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("b5:b500").Find(what:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = ""
    Else
        rownumber = rng.Row
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rownumber, 1), Cells(rownumber, 5)).Find("").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = ""
    End If
End If

Application.Goto ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), True
End Sub
```

So far, I tried adding the second line, originally I had
"If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then"

But it didn't seem to work either. I was getting errors with the keyword Me, so I changed it to Sheets("my_sheet_name") but that didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look into [worksheet change events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change` event handler belongs in a sheet code module, not a regular module.

Comment: `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then` is the correct approach.

Comment: See my comment in your previous post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76560356/all-of-the-sudden-getting-excel-vba-error-code-91-object-variable-or-with-bloc

Comment: Also note  - `Range("A1").Address` is "$A$1" not "A1".  You need `Range("A1").Address(False, False)` to get "A1"